# CSS Div positioning 4 divs(using grid)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I have 4 div blocks with information inside 1 div. How do I make them closer to each other?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL45r.png)

here's the code

```
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing how you are sizing the divs it's not possible to help. Do you actually want them as 1fr each? It sounds more like you want them a certain size and everything bunched up and centered - in which case use justify-content: center and size auto not 1fr.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);` & `place-content:center;`
you can now change your gaps even to 0

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap:10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  place-content:center;
}

.list>img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299171054-e679f630a776?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299142018-4f7f33aea18c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299170237-2d4cd59b5156?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw2MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299170936-0531a116c87c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyMXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
</div>
```